# Google Drive API works in Python script but not after Pyinstaller compilation - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'files'

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pyinstaller, exe

I have a problem with a python script after generating an exe file. The script works fine from within the .py file, but after compiling the .exe file there is an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'files'.

I want it to be an exe file so that the script can be easily and quickly run by people without a programming background.

```
def find_exact_file_id(order):
    design_code = order.code + ".png"

    query = f"'{order.design_folder_id}' in parents and name = '{design_code}'"
    page_token = None

    print(f"Search: {design_code}")
    while True:
        response = service.files().list(q=query, fields='files(id, name)', pageToken=page_token).execute()
        if 'files' in response:
            for file in response.get('files', []):
                print(f"Found file: {file.get('name')}, {file.get('id')}\n")
            design_id_response = response.get('files', [])
            page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
            if page_token is None:
                break
        else:
            design_id_response = None
            break

    if design_id_response:
        design_id = design_id_response[0]['id']
        file_name = design_id_response[0]['name']
        return design_id, file_name

    else:
        print(f"Not found: {design_code}")
        return None, None
```

and here is what i get from exe windowed file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BLOrders_v3.py", line 283, in <module>
  File "BLOrders_v3.py", line 155, in get_orders
  File "BLOrders_v3.py", line 114, in __init__
  File "BLOrders_v3.py", line 192, in recursive_find_exact_file_id
  File "BLOrders_v3.py", line 169, in find_exact_file_id
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'files'
```

I tried to compile the script both as windowed and terminal version. To compile this file I used Pyinstaller.

Comment: where is `service` defined?

Comment: @JonSG Aah sorry, I attached only one function from my script. I define it in my main function:

    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = resource_path('credentials.json')
    else:
        CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'credentials.json'
    API_NAME = 'drive'
    API_VERSION = 'V3'
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

    service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)

Comment: Well then Create_Service is the part that isn't working, because it is returning None instead of a Service instance and that is what is causing the error.

Comment: Yeah now I see the problem. Inside Create_Service it returns None:

    try:
        service = build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=cred)
        print(API_SERVICE_NAME, 'service created successfully')
        return service
    except Exception as e:
        print('Unable to connect.')
        print(e)
        return None